# Dynamic filters (different strings) for multiple sheets (different sheets in the same workbook) VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have a sheet named 'Anwendung' in a workbook where in column AI there are different fields based on which i am filtering. In this case it would be 'Anwendung'. For this i have managed to google and tweak certain section of the code and the code looks like this

```
Sub DynamicFilter()
SearchCol = "Typ"
SearchFor = "Anwendung"
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:=SearchFor
End Sub
```

Now I have a couple of other sheets in the workbook where i need to filter them according to other strings for e.g. 'Ressourcen' in column AI. With the above stated code i can just apply it for the active sheet and not the entire work book.

If I define `Dim ws As Worksheet` and then run a for loop in it. Then it filters all the sheets in the workbook with 'Anwendung' as filter criteria and for certain sheets the filter criteria is different.

```
Sub DynamicFilter()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate
SearchCol = "Typ"
SearchFor = "Anwendung"
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:=SearchFor
Next ws
End Sub
```

All i need is how can i define multiple filters for multiple sheets. Filter 1 'Anwendung' for a sheet 1 and Filter 2: 'Ressourcen' for sheet 2 as a filter for another sheet and so on.

---

#### Solved

Had to record the Macro, execute it and tweak it a bit.

```
Sheets("Anwendungen").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=15
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AZ$10637").AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:= _
        "Anwendung"
    Sheets("Ressourcen").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=16
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AZ$10637").AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "Gebäude", "IT-System", "Netz", "Raum"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Where is the `Anwendung` originally stored? is it in a specific (*same*) cell on each worksheet or is that the worksheet's name?

Comment: @vba4all- Anwendung is the name of the sheet as well as stored as Anwendungen, resourcen, Netz etc in column AI. And i am trying to filter sheet name= Anwendung with the filter in column AI= Anwendung and similarly for ressourcen.

Comment: @vba4all- Thank you very much. But it does exactly the same what i described earlier when i loop it using for. When i use the SearchFor.range= ws.Range("AI1") it filters for all the rows in the entire workbook with 'Anwendung'. Although i have a sheet with the name 'Ressourcen' and in column AI there is 'Resourcen' as a cell value. What i really need is 2 filters. Filter 1= Anwendung that i can run on Anwendung sheet. Filter 2= Ressourcen that i can rund on ressourcen sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the criteria is the worksheet name all it takes is assigning the name to the `SearchFor` variable

```
Sub DynamicFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        SearchCol = "Typ"
        SearchFor = ws.Name
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter
        ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:=SearchFor
    Next ws
End Sub
```

In case the criteria for the `SearchFor` is a cell you can assign the cell's value to that variable like this:

```
SearchFor = ws.Range("AI1")
```